# Javascript variable function does not persist values

Tags: javascript

This js function is part of a global variable.  The first time it is called, from another js file, it works.  But the second time, from itself, everything null.

```
 Start: function () {
   console.log('InactivityAlerts.Start() called ...');
    if (this.active) {
        if (this.IDLE_TIMEOUT != "") {
            window.setInterval(this.CheckIdleTime, 1000);
            console.log('started...');
        }
        else {
            window.setTimeout(this.Start, 1000);
             //an iframe sets the IDLE_TIMEOUT later, but this should continue to 
             //run until it is not blank.
        }
    }
},
```

When it calls itself again; however, everything is null, including *this.active* which was set from an Init prior to this.  Why?  And how can I make sure everything is still set right?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a `this` value issue, make sure you are binding the correct `this` value when passing functions around.

```
window.setInterval(this.CheckIdleTime.bind(this), 1000);
window.setTimeout(this.Start.bind(this), 1000);
```

You can also bind these at construction time if you always want them bound to the same instance.

```
function YourConstructor() {
    //assumes that someFunction is defined on YourConstructor.prototype
    this.someFunction = this.someFunction.bind(this);
}
```

Or the same with a well-known instance:

```
InactivityAlerts = {
    Start: function () { /*...*/ }
};

InactivityAlerts.Start = InactivityAlerts.Start.bind(InactivityAlerts);
```

Comment: @AdamRackis Yeah! Finally ;) I believe it's harder to get high rep these days hehe. When I see 200k+ rep users it's quite discouraging.

Comment: Ha - well those 200K people have been here for years and years, and rack up rep on old questions without having to do much.  Don't be discouraged!  It took me many, many obsessive hours to hit 10K—fortunately I was in an easy job at the time :)

Comment: Awesome!  In all my years with js, I have never encountered this.  Thanks again

Comment: Haha, glad I could help.  Is this also the case for variable properties? (ie. this.active)  Or will they always reference itself correctly?

Comment: @GregGamm Well the issue simply doesn't exist with non-function values. If `this.active` is boolean and you pass it around it will definitely stay the same in every contexts. However if you have a `this.isActive` function that returns `this.active` and you pass it around without explicitely binding the function e.g. `var isActive = obj.isActive;` now when you will call `isActive()` it will not return what you expect since `this` during the function execution will not be `obj` anymore.